# RewriteRule .htaccess allow all charcters

Tags: .htaccess

I have a `RewriteRule` for `.htaccess` and I want to allow all characters in the URL.

I filter out any bad characters through PHP

The code I currently have is

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.php$ file.php?key=$1 [L]
```

I tried changing it to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ file.php?key=$1 [L]
```

to allow everything to go through but it doesn't work. I don't want to filter anything at .htaccess only PHP. Is there a security risk to allow all chacters even though I filter them out in PHP?

Comment: What do the server logs say? What status are you getting? `404 - Not found`?

Comment: @OskarHane it works fine I just don't want .htaccess filtering my varibles I only want to do it php which it has already been implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to check if the file exist before redirecting it so you don't fall on a infinite loop:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ file.php?key=$1 [L]
```

The first line verify if the file exist, if it does not exist it redirects.

The second line as you already had it will redirect, `anything.php` to `file.php?key=anything` otherwise `file.php` will redirect itself to `file.php` over and over for example.

And yes, there is no problem allowing anything on the URL as long as you properly sanitize the information with your PHP code before using it.

Comment: I guess I had it right but then realized the key=$1 is only working for the files name, how would I add multiple variables that pass through .htaccess to php?

Comment: @AbbyE you mean if you have something like `anything.php?var1=something`? If so you can use the QSA(query string append) flag to keep the variables, `[QSA,L]`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a security risk to allow all chacters even though I filter them out in PHP?

Yes there are see this question:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11234/how-does-hacking-work

This depends on your application but .htaccess can be used as a security mechanism.

Comment: My file.php code is protected from SQL injection and the php filters key=$1 for any html or funny chars.